# DML Exception in test class

Tags: exception

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a0W61000002sO4NEAU; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE,
>   cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] Stack
>   Trace Class.EMPYRAMDM.REST_ContactService_V1HandlerClass.createReferenceRecord:
>   line 149, column 1 Class.EMPYRAMDM.REST_ContactService_V1.doPostCon:
>   line 48, column 1 Class.EMPYRAMDM.restContactAPI_Test.testParse: line
>   65, column 1

Comment: need yur help in fixing this error,,thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: As per the error message, you are specifying an `Id` for the object you are inserting. Better you post the related code

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? The context in which the action takes place? The code that's causing the issue? As it is, it's a very lazy question

Comment: Hi, @sasfdc. please take some time to read [ask] =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to the question:

1. If you are trying to insert/update at the same time, you could replace `insert` with `upsert`

So, `insert lstRecords` becomes `upsert lstRecords`

2. You could iterate the list of records and make the id null before inserting like this:

```
for(Object__c rec : lstRecords){
    rec.put('Id', null);
}
insert lstRecords;
```